# Google Drive Java API V2 vs V3

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I want to develop a new java application which uses google drive within our google domain. There are version 2 and version 3. I used version 2 on a another application.

Where are the main differances between v2 and v3? 
can i use v2 without any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feature wise these version are more or less the same. However, for new development v3 is recommended strongly

- It is production quality. Rule one: for new developments always use the *latest* production quality release
- The v3 API is simplified, see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7YH6rdR-tk) for details, so easier to work with
- The v3 API is *much* faster for several methods (up to 3 times)

Answer (score 1):

You can use V2 it hasn't been deprecated yet.  However V2 is older then v3 so there for we can assume that it will be deprecated before V3.  This will mean you will have to switch to the newer version at sometime in the future.

Also there will probably not be many enhancements or fixes to bugs in V2 leaving you to deal with that.

IMO when possible its always best to use the newest version of an API.  I have not heard of any major issues with V3 even though it is rather new.  There is a limited amount of documentation and examples for it though.